# how to get the cpu cache associativity settings on windows

Tags: windows, caching, architecture, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

How could I get information about the L1,L2 and L3 associativity settings? I can get the size but not the associativity, any idea?

so far I haven't found anything usefull

Answer (score 2):

The [x86 `CPUID` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CPUID.html) doesn't require any privileges, so you can run it in a program for any OS.

It has cache associativity information in leaf 2 (`eax=2`).  See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for more links to docs.

It only works on x86, though, so if you care about portability to Windows on non-x86, you'll have to find something else for other architectures.

There are libraries to decode this CPUID info, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel by writing a decoding function, and the asm function or inline asm to run CPUID in the first place.